# Analogue of Cartan theorem A in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Before starting algebraic geometry, I got some understanding of Compact Riemann Surfaces which is more or less rigorous; and then I attended a couple of lectures on analytic geometry. I did not quite fully grasp the analytic geometry rigorously; but it stuck in my mind and this previous experiences helped me greatly when learning algebraic geometry. However I am not able to imagine what would be the precise analogue of Cartan's Theorem A for algebraic varieties over a field. There is the wikipedia article:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan's_theorems_A_and_B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_theorems_A_and_B)

which tells me the precise analogue of Cartan Theorem B in the book of Hartshorne. And indeed it is really analogous. But it does not mention Theorem A. Note that here I am restricting the situation to varieties out of fear of any pathologies schemes might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over an affine scheme any quasi-coherent sheaf is generated by its global sections, so I guess Theorem A is always true.

Comment: Ah! Was rather stupid of me not to find it out by myself. Thank you.

Comment: Heh, no problem, I just learned about it from Hartshorne!